# How to get height of a browser window and then set a height of a div to that value

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

When I open a page I want to get full-height background image.
[Like this](https://wordpress.com/)

I haven't started using jQuery yet, so if you could help me with basic js.   This is what I tried so far, but it wasn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/basic.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="front-page" class="window_height_picture" onload="get_window_height()">
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>   
</html>
```

And this is my .js file:

```
function get_window_height() {
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById('front-page').style.height = window_height + 'px';
}
```

I did search for this, but couldn't find what I was looking for. Can you tell me where I was wrong, or provide me with a better code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pure CSS Solution

No need for JavaScript at all. Use the `vh` viewport length unit in your CSS.

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> — [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

This unit specifically sets the length to be equal to a percentage of the **v**iewport **h**eight (where `1vh` is 1% of the viewport height, etc.) Here you want `100vh` (100% of the viewport height):

```css
#front-page {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

An popular answer of mine which I posted to a different question here on Stack Overflow goes into a lot of detail about what the `vh` unit is: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window/16837667#16837667).

Comment: Yea, that does it. I didn't know it was that simple -.- Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may have noticed that in the example you provided, wordpress.com theme uses a `background-size: cover;` for the background image.

See [MDN's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) or [this friendly tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: Yes, I used that css property, but if i figured it out, I think that only works for the given height and width, it can't set it to window height, am I right?

Comment: No that doesn't set the height to the viewport's height indeed. Just wanted to make sure that you didn't miss this very handy property :-)